# Map cache supertile boundaries

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, mapcache

I'm updating a cached map service by features at different scale levels to only recreate tiles over changed data.

It works fine, but it occurred to me it might be more efficient to cache by super-tile extents, so if multiple of my caching features are within the same super-tile area it doesn't re-cache the same area multiple times.

Does anyone know if there is a way to visualize or map super-tile areas?

I know I can see the bundle areas with the task status fc in the cache status.gdb but the bundle areas are potentially much larger than a super-tile.

I'm using ArcGIS Server 10.1 sp1.

Comment: @BenSNadler - great find with the tool.  I checked in 10.1 and it's there too.  If you want to add your comment as a response I'll accept it as the answer.   I ran the tool and compared its polygon results (super-tile boundaries) to actual tiles and they line up, giving me assurance the tool is working correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool for this starting at 10.1. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/cartography-toolbox/map-server-cache-tiling-scheme-to-polygons.htm#